# (Unity)How to rotate child object regardless of orientation?

Tags: unity-game-engine, orientation

So I have 4 objects, which all have childs underneath. I want to rotate these childs slowly when a button is pressed.

Example: Spacebar is pressed, and for all 4 parent objects I want to rotate the child down slowly. Problem is, they need to use the same script, but all of their orientations are different.

So if I do the following:
[image]

Childs of parent 1 move down perfectly, but childs of parent 2 move to the left and right, because they have a different orientation. When I rotate them by hand in Unity, for parent 1's childs I need to move the Y axis to get them to rotate down, but for parent 2's childs it's the Z axis.

How can i always move it down regardless of any orientation?

Answer (score 0):

[`Rotate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html)

has an optional parameter **relativeTo**. By default it is set to `Space.Self` what you want is `Space.World` so do

```
pBone.transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * _boneMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried that, but that only gives me a more weird situation where I can get neither of the objects to rotate down, instead they rotate around

Comment: @Patrick well it depends which axis you want to rotate around ... `Vector3.up` is the Y axis ... you probably rather want to use `Vector3.right` (X axis) or `Vector3.forward` (Z axis)

Comment: I tried all of those. I think the point were missing is that the 3D models differ them selves. I just found out about this thing called left and right handed coordinates/vectors. Seems to be in the model. So as I stated above for one model Y axis is up and down, for the other Z axis is. I can use Space.World but that still results in really odd behaviour. If I know how to find out in code if a model is left or right handed I can use that to simply say either use vector3.down or vector3.right but I have no clue how. as for your suggestion, I tried all Vector3 directions, as well as transform

Comment: You can't find out in code if a model is originally left- or right-handed ... You can however in Unity attach the all as children to some empty parent GameObjects and rotate them correctly locally. Then in the code instead transform and rotate the parents .. and we'll using Space.World it actually shouldn't matter how the 3d models are oriented .. it would rotate them in world space ...